# getting an error when I call this Dijkstra function

Tags: python, dijkstra, shortest-path

When I call this function, the error below is raised, any idea is really appreciated.

The error:
    dist, next = Dijkstra(graph, sink, sources)
            line 111, in Dijkstra
    S, Q = list(sources[:]), range(1,n+1)
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

The code:

```
def Dijkstra(graph, sink, sources = None):
    n = len (graph.nodes ())
    dist = {k+1:np.inf for k in range(n)}
    next = {k+1:None for k in range(n)}
    dist[sink] = 0.0
    S = list(sources[:])
    Q = range(1,n+1)
    while len(Q)>0:
        min = np.inf
        for v in Q:
            if (dist[v] < min):
                u=v
                min = dist[v]
        if min == np.inf: return dist, next
        for s in S:
            if u == s: S.remove(u)
        if len(S)==0: return dist,next
        Q.remove(u)
        for a in graph.predecessors_iter(u):
            v = a
            alt = dist[u] + graph [v][u]["weight"]
            if alt < dist[v]: dist[v] = alt; next[v] = u
    return dist, next


def mainKSP(graph, sources, sink, K):
"""Find the K-shortest paths from sources to sink

Return value:
-------------
As: dictionary s.t. As[s]=[K-shortest paths from s to sink for s in sources]
"""
dist, next = Dijkstra(graph, sink, sources)
A0s = {s:get_path(s, sink, next) for s in sources}
return {s : YenKSP(graph, s, sink, K, A0s[s]) for s in sources}
graphnodes = [h for h in range (1, 24)]    
path = mainKSP(network, graphnodes, 1, 3)
```

I am a python beginner and made so much afford to figure out what is wrong with the S list, but no success. The Dijkstra function is called from inside of another function provided above.

Comment: The error suggests that you're passing in an `int` for the `sources` argument. You haven't shown that call, so we can't tell why you're doing that. If you include the full traceback of the exception (instead of just the last lines), we would see the call too, I suspect.

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: The code is edited such that you can examine how the function is called. Also full trace back was added. Thanks!